# How to check if an attribute is a Dimension, Integer or Resource ID

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to make a relatively simple custom view where, depending on the location of the code, the XML describes a discrete value (`"100dp"`) or a resource value (`"@dimen/standardWidth"`).

I'm not sure how I can check wether the returned value is a resid, integer or dimension value (as getDimenion(), getInt() and getResourceID() all return the same values it seems).

I use the following code:

```
<declare-styleable name="LabeledView">
    ...
    <attr name="labelWidth" format="dimension|reference"/>
    ...
</declare-styleable>
```

And in my Custom View I use the following:

```
    if (attrs!=null) {
        TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(    
            attrs, R.styleable.LabeledView, 0, 0);

        int labelWidth = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.LabeledView_labelWidth, -1);
```

In the above example `labelWidth` is equal to 2131165193 as it's actually a resid to a @dimen.

Comment: did you try TypedArray.getValue/TypedArray.peekValue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only dimension format, without reference. However you may use reference values for the attribute. They should be read as actual dimensions.

```
<attr name="labelWidth" format="dimension"/>

typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize
```